# C function and char *

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, string-literals

I have this function:

```
void print_pol(char* pol); //or char[]
    printf("%s", pol);
}
```

In `main()`, I call this function as below

```
print_pol("pol1");
```

But I didn't allocate memory for `char* pol` in the program. So how is this possible? I know that a pointer must point to something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"poll1"` is a string literal with type length-6 array of char, `char[6]`. The data itself is stored in read-only memory. Your function parameter `pol` may look like an array, but it is adjusted to `char*`, giving you this:

```
void print_pol(char* pol){ ...
```

When you pass it the literal to the function, it decays into a pointer to its first element. No allocation is required on your side.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `"pol1"` is called a [*string literal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal). During compilation time, this data is stored into some memory area (*usually read-only memory, which cannot be altered, or atleast any attempt to alter the contents will result in  [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*) which is allocated by the compiler itself.

When you use it, you essentially pass the base address of the string literal and collect it into a `char *` ( same as `char []` in case of usage in function parameter). There is no need for any allocation from your side.

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_pol(char pol[])
{        
  printf("%s", pol);
}


int main()
{
  print_pol("pol1");
  return 0;
}
```

Once you call the function `print_pol("pol1")`, in the function definition it is converted to a pointer and `print_pol(char* pol);` `char *pol` points exactly to the first location of the character array.

Hence no memory is needed or allocated for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler compiles `print_pol("pol1")` as follows:

- Allocate a block of 5 consecutive characters in a read-only memory segment of the executable image, containing the characters `'p'`, `'o'`, `'l'`, `'1'` followed by the null character (`'\0'`).
- Pass the memory address of that block to function `print_pol`.

So to answer your question, the compiler allocates this memory.